# Separating Intents in Accessibility Service

Tags: java, android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have an `AccessibilityService` which listens for a specific application opening and reacts when it detects it, what it does when detected is not relevant to the issue:

```
public class AccServ extends AccessibilityService {

    static final String TAG = "AccServ";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if(event.getPackageName().equals("com.test.package"))
            // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onInterrupt");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();

        ServiceMan.Start(getApplicationContext());

        Log.v(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.test.package"};
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

}
```

The package `com.test.package` can be launched through 2 intents: `com.test.package/main` and `com.test.package/secondary`.

In short I need to separate these 2 intents as I only want it to react when the main intent is called.

I can't seem to get this information from the AccessibilityEvent. I also  considered manually checking the current intent of the open application however as I don't share the signature I am not allowed access to that information. I have no control over the application I am listening for.

Thanks for any help.